Wordpress: Music Playing in background - change page content and the music continues to play
Using an overlay and button we can play a company theme song when someone lands on the page.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Add event listeners here
    document.getElementById("playButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("audioContainer").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("audio").play();
    });

    document.getElementById("svgIcon").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
        if (audio.paused) {
            audio.play();
        } else {
            audio.pause();
        }
    });
});

We want the music to play on a continuous loop uninterrupted when they navigate to a new page. We think the music is a nice touch and enhances the user experience. It works perfectly on the homepage. Before you ask why or tell us not to do it, we want to.
A second page will load using an iframe:
async function load_home(e) {
    (e || window.event).preventDefault();

    try {
        const response = await fetch("https://trimarcconstruction.com/homepage" /*, options */);
        const html = await response.text();
        
        // Create an iframe element
        const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        
        // Set the srcdoc attribute to the HTML content
        iframe.srcdoc = html;
        
        // Set styles to make the iframe fill the whole screen
        iframe.style.position = 'fixed';
        iframe.style.top = '0';
        iframe.style.left = '0';
        iframe.style.width = '100vw';
        iframe.style.height = '100vh';
        iframe.style.border = 'none'; // Optional
        
        // Append the iframe to the document body
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
}

Other javascript functions are not working on the second page.
The site is too big to load all the pages in one HTML document.
I have created a div and on and changing with innerhtml but it breaks: https://trimarcconstruction.com/innerhtml_test/
You can demo it here: trimarcconstruction.com.
How do get the music to play on a continuous loop while the visitor navigates the site?
